# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

ошибка при `writer.writerow` 
 
В начале файла стоит

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

def save(projects, path):
    with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(('name', 'brend', 'descr', 'image', 'radiys', 'price'))
        s = projects[0]['proj'][0]['text']
        writer.writerow((projects[0]['proj'][0]['name'], projects[0]['proj'][0]['brand'], s, projects[0]['proj'][0]['image'], projects[0]['proj'][1]['price'], projects[0]['proj'][1]['radiys']))
        writer.writerows(
            ('', '', '', '', project['price'], project['radiys']) for project in projects[0]['proj'][2:]
        )
    print('Сохранение...')
    save(printmass , 'projects.csv')
```

Текст прихродит руский ошибка-

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 28-32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

если `print(projects[0]['proj'][0]['text'])`  покажет консоль русский текст.

Comment: unrelated: Не нужно повторять `projects[0]['proj'][0]` в одной строчке несколько раз. Для лучшей читаемости, используйте переменную, например: `prj = projects[0]['proj'][0]`, а потом `prj['name']`, `prj['image']`, etc

Comment: для меня и так понятно, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно локаль у вас не настроена (см. `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE`, `LANG` переменные окружения на POSIX) и поэтому `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` возвращает `'ascii'`.

Чтобы не зависеть от локали, можно явно кодировку текста указать:

```
with open(path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    ...
```

Comment: спасибо, первый раз на python пишу =)